# How to see that the strategy $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ is a Nash equilibrium in this simple game?

Tags: game-theory

Consider the payoff matrix,
$$\begin{bmatrix} (0,0) & (-1,1)\\ 
(1,-1) & (-10,-10)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Assume players want to maximize payoff.

If the row player choses strategy $(1,0)$ i.e., strategy 1. Then the column player must choose strategy $(0,1)$ to maximize his payoff  ($0$ vs $1$)

But then the row player wants to change to strategy $2$ to change his payoff from $-1$ to $1$. At this point, the column player can only change to strategy $1$ to avoid a payoff of $-10$.

This means the pure Nash of this game is $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$ and the solution $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ will be forever unstable (one player will always want to change).

Why is that $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ is a solution when computed? https://intranet.csc.liv.ac.uk/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/rahul/input.py

---

Is the algorithm for computing pure NE:

1. First consider case when row player move first?
2. Next consider case when column player move first?

I think this 2 is what I am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the row player chooses strategy 1, the column player can choose between payoff 0 or 1, and will therefore go with 1 (i.e. strategy 2). If the column player chooses strategy 2, the row player can choose between payoff -1 and -10, and will therefore choose -1 (i.e. strategy 1)

So row 1, column 2 is a Nash equilibrium. As is row 2, column 1 for analogous reasons.

Comment: So computing the NE what are essentially simultaneously games....we have to pretend that the players are computing them sequentially? I thought matrix games were simultaneously games

Comment: @SanjayGupta Yes, because NEs are about whether the players would change their minds about their strategies if they played the same game again. And take into account what their opponent played last time.